# Scala REPL crashes when started using scala.tools.nsc.interpreter

Tags: scala, debugging, read-eval-print-loop, scala-2.11

I'm trying to use `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter` to enable interactive debugging (like Python's pdb/ipdb):

```
val foo = 123

import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.{ ILoop, SimpleReader }

val repl = new ILoop
repl.settings = new Settings
repl.settings.usejavacp.value = true
repl.in = SimpleReader()
repl.createInterpreter()

repl.intp.bind("foo", "Int", foo)

repl.loop()
repl.closeInterpreter()
```

When run, this is what I get:

```
$ scala repl.scala
foo: Int = 123

scala> "hello"   
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:95)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:95)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.ready(package.scala:95)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:402)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:430)
    at Main$$anon$1.<init>(repl.scala:14)
    at Main$.main(repl.scala:1)
    at Main.main(repl.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.scala$tools$nsc$ScriptRunner$$runCompiled(ScriptRunner.scala:175)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:192)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:192)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:161)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScriptRunner.scala:161)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:129)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:129)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.trackingThreads(package.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.waitingForThreads(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:128)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:192)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:205)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:67)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)


Abandoning crashed session.

scala>
```

If I remove the `repl.intp.bind("foo", "Int", foo)` part, this is what I get:

```
$ scala repl.scala 

scala> 123
null

Abandoning crashed session.

scala>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there an easier way to drop into an interactive REPL during a program run for debugging purposes? breakpoints, stepping through and inspecting locals just doesn't do it sometimes.

I'm on Scala 2.11.5.

Comment: You might try Scalive: https://github.com/xitrum-framework/scalive

Comment: @GáborBakos: thanks a lot; seems potentially very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this comment doesn't have the magic asterisks:

```
  // start an interpreter with the given settings
  def process(settings: Settings): Boolean
```

So you can:

```
scala> repl process s
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :quit
res0: Boolean = true
```

Or you could:

```
package myrepl

import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.{ ILoop, SimpleReader }

object Test extends App {
  val foo = 42
  val repl = new ILoop {
    override def printWelcome() = {
      intp.bind("foo", foo)
      super.printWelcome()
      echo("Customized...")
    }
  }
  val s = new Settings
  s.usejavacp.value = true
  repl.in = SimpleReader()
  repl process s
  /*
  repl.createInterpreter()

  repl.intp.bind("foo", "Int", foo)

  repl.loop()
  repl.closeInterpreter()
  */
}
```

And

```
$ scalac myrepl.scala && scala myrepl.Test
foo: Int = 42
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Customized...

scala> foo
res0: Int = 42

scala> :quit
```

Also,

```
  s.Xnojline.value  = true
  //repl.in = SimpleReader()
```

I'm going to downgrade to 2.11.4 because of the repl crashing bug...

Sbt does it by [overriding `createInterpreter` and calling bind there](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/compile/interface/src/main/scala/xsbt/ConsoleInterface.scala#L27).

Edit:

```
  val repl = new ILoop {
    override def printWelcome() = {
      //import scala.concurrent.duration._
      //Await.ready(globalFuture, 10.minutes) // sorry, it's private!
      super.printWelcome()
      echo("Customizing...")
      processLine("") // block for init to finish
      intp.bind("foo", foo)
    }
  }
```

The private `globalFuture` is an impediment to exploding the startup:

```
object Solid extends App {
  val foo = 42
  val repl = new ILoop {
    override def printWelcome() = {
      super.printWelcome()
      echo("Customized...")
    }
  }
  val s = new Settings
  s.Xnojline.value = true
  s.usejavacp.value = true
  repl.settings = s
  repl.createInterpreter()
  repl.in = SimpleReader()
  repl.intp.initializeSynchronous()
  repl.loopPostInit()
  repl.globalFuture = concurrent.Future.successful(true)

  repl.intp.bind("foo", "Int", foo)

  try repl.loop()
  finally repl.closeInterpreter()
}
```

The `-Yrepl-sync` option is no longer honored in 2.11.

Comment: thanks! if I replace the `.loop()` call with `.process(repl.settings)`, it works as advertised, however, evaling `foo` yields `error: not found: value foo` — is it possible to bind names to the REPL?

Comment: @ErikAllik The startup needs to be redone, also witness how sbt does its console init. There's also -i for misc init, too.

Comment: Running your code unchanged on 2.11.4 or 2.11.5 gives me: `scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving object Predef` and then if I keep retrying, it, non-deterministically, either works, or prints the same error but doesn't crash...

Comment: @ErikAllik calling `processLine` in `printWelcome` is my best trick for waiting for compiler init to complete. See edit. HTH.